# file doesn't recognize the existence of a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is saved in file A.
The macro is supposed to be ran from another file - lets call it file B (which is a regular excel file - .xlsx). 
when opening the VBA editor from file B, I don't see the macro of file A in the list on the left.
If I try to open the VBA editor from file A, it opens a separate editor, although it is supposed to go to the same editor, which is already open.
Because of the above, I cannot run the macro. Note, that it works for users on another computer, so it is something in my settings.

I don't know if how it can be related, but there is another thing that started happening also recently.
I created a few macros and saved in the PERSONAL.XLSB. It worked few a few weeks without any problem, but now, every time I open almost any excel file, I get an error massage saying:
file in use PERSONAL.XLSB is locked for editing by 'my name' open 'REad-Only' or click 'Notify' to open read-only and receive notification when the documents is no longer in use.

I probably did something to change the setting, but I can't figure out what.
Note, that the macro did work fine for quite a few months, even after I added macros to the PERSONAL.XLSB file.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have 2 instances of Excel running. To access file B from your macro in file A they should probably be in the same instance. ① how do you open file A and file B, by macro or manually? If by macro please share the macro. ② What you can try is backup and then delete your PERSONAL.XLSB to test if this causes all the issues.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks. I open both files manually. I tried to delete the personal file and it didn't work, still having hte same issue. Now when I am on file B, when I click on Macros from the developer tab, it is empty (before it showed all my macros from the personal.xlsb). Any other suggestions why it opens in separate instances?

Comment: When's the last time you restarted Windows? It sounds as if there are "orphaned" instances of Excel running... Possibly you have an add-in or some other software that works with Excel that's generating instances?

Comment: @CindyMeister restarted a few times today after every possible solution I tried for this problem:(

Comment: What do you see in Processes in the Task Manager? Are there multiple instances of Excel listed? When you say "open both files manually": How exactly are you doing this: from Excel's File/Open menu or through Windows Explorer?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window) help?. Maybe, reverse engineer it

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find what caused the problem, but uninstalling and installing office solved it.